# Is it possible to navigate from a tab bar controller to another tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, tabbar

I have an app with three tabs as the root navigation, and there's a table view in the first tab. So when a user clicks on a table cell user should navigate to another View which contains two tabs. How do I achieve this?

**Current Storyboard**

[image]

This is what I have so far. I'm still learning ios development and I want to know if this is possible

Comment: You can do this

Comment: How do I pass data in to the second tab controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the storyboard segue from the table view to the second tab bar controller. And present the second tab bar controller from the table view controller's `didSelectRowAt` method. And you can pass data to the embedded view controllers like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let secondTabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTabBarController") as?  SecondTabBarController {
        if let navControllers = secondTabBarController.viewControllers as? [UINavigationController] {
            if let fourthVC = navControllers.first(where: { $0.topViewController is FourthVC })?.topViewController as? FourthVC {
                fourthVC.name = "name"
            }
            if let fifthVCvc = navControllers.first(where: { $0.topViewController is FifthVC })?.topViewController as? FifthVC {
                fifthVCvc.id = 20
            }
        }
        self.present(secondTabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Replace the class names and storyboard identifiers with proper class names and identifiers

```
class FourthVC: UIViewController {
    var name: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(name)
    }
}
class FifthVC: UIViewController {
    var id: Int?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(id)
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way how do i get the back button in the navigation bar?

Comment: So if I use nav.pushViewController() instead of present() i think i could get the same behavior right and get the second tab controller attached to first tab controller's navigation

Comment: @SenuraSeneviratne yes you can use. Before using nav.pushViewController() hide navigation bar of first tab controller else sencond tab controller's navigation bar won't be visible

Answer (score 0):

Yes you set any check for that in a single tab controller by this condition which tab you want to show  reset from their.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on the row from the table view, you can use some code like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Segue to the other UITabBarController, pass selected information

        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath.row)

        if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourTabBarControllerIdentifier") as? YourTabBarController {
            viewController.selectedIndex = 2 // or the index you want by default
            viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // or transition you want

            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```